# interchange 2 strings in file terminal command

Tags: text, text-processing

I want to swap 2 strings in a file

Here is the example

```
[ link ]( text )
```

I want to make it

```
[ text ]( link )
```

how can i do this ? i tried something with while but i can't make it

link = http://something.com etc 
text can be anything

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "[ link ]( text )" | perl -pe 's/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/[$2]($1)/g'
[ text ]( link )
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash, assuming the bracketing and white space is fixed, this will do it:

`a=$(echo "[ link ]( text )" | cut -d ' ' -f 4) ; b=$(echo "[ link ]( text )" | cut -d ' ' -f 2) ; echo "[ $a ]( $b )"`

You could make it shorter, but hopefully this way is clear in how it works. If you want it as a script, replace the input text with "$1".

To input from a file use `read` instead.